# how to fix Hibernate exception entity altered from 1 to 0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to generate MySQL table from Hibernate. My entity has one to one relation between them. Here is the code:-

BuyerPartyDetails class:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyerPartyDetails")
public class BuyerPartyDetails {
    /**
     * For annotation all subsequent properties name must be presented as same as in XML file.
     */

    // for buyerPartyDetails table primary key
    int buyerPartyDetailsId;

    // Xml node and buyerPartyDetails.BuyerOrganisationName column
    @XmlElement
    private String BuyerOrganisationName;

    // Xml node and buyerPartyDetails.BuyerPartyIdentifier column
    //@XmlElement
    @Transient
    private String BuyerPartyIdentifier;
    // it is for database column name. Otherwise it conflicts with xml annotation
    private String buyid;

    @Column(name = "buyerPartyIdentifier")
    public String getBuyid() {
        return buyid;
    }

    public void setBuyid(String buyid) {
        this.buyid = buyid;
    }


    // Xml node and buyerPostalAddressDetails table
    // Set provides annotation for xml parser.
    // Get provides annotation for Database framework (Entity).
    private BuyerPostalAddressDetails buyerPostalAddressDetails;


    // Xml node and invoiceDetails table
    private Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetails>(0);
    // must annotate in getter method for database
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "buyerPartyDetails")
    public Set<InvoiceDetails> getInvoiceDetails() {
        return invoiceDetails;
    }

    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "buyerPostalAddressDetails", type = BuyerPartyDetails.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "buyerPostalAddressDetails", type = BuyerPartyDetails.class) })
    public void setInvoiceDetails(Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails) {
        this.invoiceDetails = invoiceDetails;
    }

    //@Column(name = "XmlFileName")
    String xmlFileName;


    @Column(name = "XmlFileName")
    public String getXmlFileName() {
        return xmlFileName;
    }

    public void setXmlFileName(String xmlFileName) {
        this.xmlFileName = xmlFileName;
    }

    /**
     * All properties setter and getter
     */

    // must annotate in getter method for database
    // buyerPartyDetails.BuyerPartyDetails_id table column.
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "buyerPartyDetails_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getBuyerPartyDetails_id() {
        return buyerPartyDetailsId;
    }


    public void setBuyerPartyDetails_id(int buyerPartyDetails_id) {
        buyerPartyDetailsId = buyerPartyDetails_id;
    }

    // must annotate in getter method for database
    // buyerPartyDetails table has one to one relation with buyerPostalAddressDetails table
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "buyerPartyDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public BuyerPostalAddressDetails getBuyerPostalAddressDetails() {
        return buyerPostalAddressDetails;
    }

    @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "BuyerPostalAddressDetails", type = BuyerPostalAddressDetails.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "BuyerPartyDetails", type = BuyerPartyDetails.class) })
    public void setBuyerPostalAddressDetails(
            BuyerPostalAddressDetails buyerPostalAddressDetails) {
        this.buyerPostalAddressDetails = buyerPostalAddressDetails;
    }

    // must annotate in getter method for database
    // buyerPartyDetails.BuyerOrganisationName column
    @Column(name = "buyerOrganisationName")
    public String getBuyerOrganisationName ()
    {
        return BuyerOrganisationName;
    }

    public void setBuyerOrganisationName (String BuyerOrganisationName)
    {
        this.BuyerOrganisationName = BuyerOrganisationName;
    }

    // must annotate in getter method for database
    // buyerPartyDetails.BuyerPartyIdentifier column
    //@Column(name = "BuyerPartyIdentifier")
    @Transient
    public String getBuyerPartyIdentifier ()
    {
        return BuyerPartyIdentifier;
    }

    @Transient
    @XmlElement(name = "BuyerPartyIdentifier")
    public void setBuyerPartyIdentifier (String BuyerPartyIdentifier)
    {
        this.BuyerPartyIdentifier = BuyerPartyIdentifier;
        buyid = BuyerPartyIdentifier;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BuyerPartyDetails [buyerPostalAddressDetails="
                + buyerPostalAddressDetails + ", BuyerOrganisationName="
                + BuyerOrganisationName + ", BuyerPartyIdentifier="
                + BuyerPartyIdentifier + "]";
    }
}
```

BuyerPostalAddressDetails :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyerPostalAddressDetails")
public class BuyerPostalAddressDetails {

    int buyerPartyDetailsId;

    @XmlElement
    private String BuyerTownName;

    @XmlElement
    private String BuyerPostCodeIdentifier;

    @XmlElement
    private String BuyerStreetName;

    private BuyerPartyDetails buyerPartyDetails;


    // must annotate in getter method for database
    // buyerPostalAddressDetails table has one to one relation with buyerPartyDetails table.
    // buyerPostalAddressDetails.BuyerPartyDetails_id table column.
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "buyerPartyDetails"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public int getBuyerPartyDetails_id() {
        return buyerPartyDetailsId;
    }

    public void setBuyerPartyDetails_id(int BuyerPartyDetails_id) {
        BuyerPartyDetails_id = BuyerPartyDetails_id;
    }

    public String getBuyerTownName() {
        return BuyerTownName;
    }

    public void setBuyerTownName(String buyerTownName) {
        BuyerTownName = buyerTownName;
    }

    public String getBuyerPostCodeIdentifier() {
        return BuyerPostCodeIdentifier;
    }

    public void setBuyerPostCodeIdentifier(String buyerPostCodeIdentifier) {
        BuyerPostCodeIdentifier = buyerPostCodeIdentifier;
    }

    public String getBuyerStreetName() {
        return BuyerStreetName;
    }

    public void setBuyerStreetName(String buyerStreetName) {
        BuyerStreetName = buyerStreetName;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public BuyerPartyDetails getBuyerPartyDetails() {
        return buyerPartyDetails;
    }

    public void setBuyerPartyDetails(BuyerPartyDetails buyerPartyDetails) {
        this.buyerPartyDetails = buyerPartyDetails;
    }

}
```

When I run the code. I can see that MySQL tables are generated in the database:-

[image]

Explain table buyerpartydetails:-

[image]

Explain table buyerpostaladdressdetails:-

[image]

When I tried to insert data into the table I got an exception as:-

> identifier of an instance of
>   com.ma.home.model.BuyerPostalAddressDetails was altered from 1 to 0

What is wrong with my table and how to fix it?

XML file for parsing:-

It is a huge file. so I am sharing just one node from the XML file:-

```
      <Finvoice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.01" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Finvoice.xsd">
        <SellerPartyDetails>
          <SellerPartyIdentifier>0101263-6</SellerPartyIdentifier>
          <SellerOrganisationName>Espoon kaupunki</SellerOrganisationName>
        </SellerPartyDetails>
        <SellerOrganisationUnitNumber>00370101263600228</SellerOrganisationUnitNumber>
        <InvoiceRecipientLanguageCode>fi</InvoiceRecipientLanguageCode>
        <BuyerPartyDetails>
          <BuyerPartyIdentifier>12227-000X</BuyerPartyIdentifier>
          <BuyerOrganisationName>Test user</BuyerOrganisationName>
          <BuyerPostalAddressDetails>
            <BuyerStreetName>KOLKEKANNAKSENTIE 10 D 7</BuyerStreetName>
            <BuyerTownName>ESPOO</BuyerTownName>
            <BuyerPostCodeIdentifier>02720</BuyerPostCodeIdentifier>
          </BuyerPostalAddressDetails>
        </BuyerPartyDetails>
        <InvoiceDetails>
          <InvoiceTypeCode>INV01</InvoiceTypeCode>
          <InvoiceTypeText>LASKU</InvoiceTypeText>
          <OriginCode>Original</OriginCode>
          <InvoiceNumber>1322818237</InvoiceNumber>
          <InvoiceDate Format="CCYYMMDD">20131024</InvoiceDate>
          <SellersBuyerIdentifier>134151</SellersBuyerIdentifier>
          <AgreementIdentifier>228004272</AgreementIdentifier>
          <DefinitionDetails>
            <DefinitionHeaderText DefinitionCode="AddressDate">Osoitteen voimaantulo</DefinitionHeaderText>
            <DefinitionValue>20040902</DefinitionValue>
          </DefinitionDetails>
          <DefinitionDetails>
            <DefinitionHeaderText DefinitionCode="Cost">Huomautuskulut</DefinitionHeaderText>
            <DefinitionValue>0,00</DefinitionValue>
          </DefinitionDetails>
          <DefinitionDetails>
            <DefinitionHeaderText DefinitionCode="Interest">Viivästyskorko</DefinitionHeaderText>
            <DefinitionValue>0,00</DefinitionValue>
          </DefinitionDetails>
          <InvoiceTotalVatIncludedAmount AmountCurrencyIdentifier="EUR">252,07</InvoiceTotalVatIncludedAmount>
          <InvoiceFreeText>KOTIHOIDON KÄYNTI LIPPAJÄRVI-JUPPERIN ALUE;TURVAPUHELIN OSTOPALVELU LIPPAJÄRVI-JUPPERIN ALUE;KOTIINKULJ.ATERIA (KH. AS.) LIPPAJÄRVI-JUPPERIN ALUE</InvoiceFreeText>
          <PaymentTermsDetails>
            <InvoiceDueDate Format="CCYYMMDD">20140224</InvoiceDueDate>
          </PaymentTermsDetails>
        </InvoiceDetails>
        <InvoiceRow>
          <RowIdentifier/>
        </InvoiceRow>
        <EpiDetails>
          <EpiIdentificationDetails>
            <EpiDate Format="CCYYMMDD">20140923</EpiDate>
            <EpiReference>0</EpiReference>
          </EpiIdentificationDetails>
          <EpiPartyDetails>
            <EpiBfiPartyDetails>
              <EpiBfiIdentifier IdentificationSchemeName="BIC">BANKFIHH</EpiBfiIdentifier>
            </EpiBfiPartyDetails>
            <EpiBeneficiaryPartyDetails>
              <EpiAccountID IdentificationSchemeName="IBAN">FI89136787</EpiAccountID>
            </EpiBeneficiaryPartyDetails>
          </EpiPartyDetails>
          <EpiPaymentInstructionDetails>
            <EpiRemittanceInfoIdentifier IdentificationSchemeName="SPY">00000082375</EpiRemittanceInfoIdentifier>
            <EpiInstructedAmount AmountCurrencyIdentifier="EUR">252,07</EpiInstructedAmount>
            <EpiCharge ChargeOption="SHA">SHA</EpiCharge>
            <EpiDateOptionDate Format="CCYYMMDD">20140224</EpiDateOptionDate>
          </EpiPaymentInstructionDetails>
        </EpiDetails>
      </Finvoice>
```

Comment: can you show your mapping XML file ?

Comment: and how you inserting data that code?

Comment: Pls check the xml file.I am inserting by the hibernate sessionFactory